# How to limit width of multiple TextFields inside a Column? Wrapping the latter with a SizedBox doesn't work

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, textfield

This is my tree:

`Scaffold(-> Column(-> Expanded(-> ListView(-> Column(-> TextFields)))));`

I want to limit the width of these TextFields (say, to 200px), but using SizedBox/Container/ConstrainedBox and setting a width/maxWidth on the Column isn't working; I have to wrap each individual TextField with a SizedBox for it to work- which adds a lot of fluff to my code.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: try to set  mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min inside the Column widget

Comment: @Nickan, that affects the height of the column. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer while watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcnP3_mO_Ms.

> "If you put AspectRatio into something like Expanded, then that will
>   be forced by its parent to expand. Tightly fitted widgets like
>   Expanded don't give their children a choice-- harsh. If this happens
>   to you, just put something like Align between the Expanded and the
>   AspectRatio.
>
> Align will be forced by Expanded to fill the area, but it will let its
>   child assume its own proportions. Thanks, Align!"

I have to wrap my `Column` in a `Container`, and then wrap the `Container` in an `Align` to break free of `Expanded`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your Column with a Container and set it to 200px, you'll not have to specify/wrap your TextFields individually anymore.

also looking at your hierarchy your Expanded widget will decide the max. width.

```
Scaffold(-> Column(-> Expanded(-> ListView(-> Container(width:200 -> Column(-> TextFields))))));

body: Container(    
          width: 200,
          color: Colors.deepOrange,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextField(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: I just tried it on DartPad, it works, can you share your code ?

Comment: try this: https://dartpad.dev/54c26ddbd57f0fbd5dca0dffd9ad718f

Comment: if you can wrap your first column with a container width of 200, that solve the issue @MaskyS

Comment: True, but the reason I have that column in the first place is because its other children take up different widths. Thanks nevertheless!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that TextField don't have a defined width so the Column doesn't know how to handle it and the Column needs to know the size of its child elements to properly render them. You best bet is wrapping your TextField in:
 1. An Expanded widget (here the TextField will expand to fill the
    available space)
 2. A Flexible widget, or
 3. Better still wrap it in a Container since you already know the width
    you want (i.e. 200px).

Answer (score 0):

Add `Container` at the top and give it `width:200`

```
Scaffold(-> Container(width:200 ->Column(-> Expanded(-> ListView(-> Column(-> TextFields)))));
```